# Symfony 5 - How manipulate a serialized object in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, symfony

I want serialize an object for get a JSON. When i serialize this object, i get this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title",
    "authors": [
        "/api/authors/1",
        "/api/authors/2"
    ]
}
```

I would like change the "Authors" data in the JSON, passing it an array. Like this example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title",
    "authors": [
        "id":1,
        "name": "Robert Smith",
        "booksCount":1
        etc etc....
    ]
}
```

And this is my actually code

```
   $book = $bookRepository->find($id);
    
    
    $authors = array("authors" => $bookRepository->find($id)->getAuthors());

    return $this->json($book, 200, []);
```

I would replace the "author" JSON values with my array in $authors.
How can i manipulate a JSON format like i want ?

Comment: Is there any piece of the code you have currently?

Comment: sorry, the post is edited

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the **json_decode** function.

PHP documentation: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php),
[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true); // return array

$json_array['authors'] = $bookRepository->find($id)->getAuthors();

$json = json_encode($json_array); //return json
```

or **@VirtualProperty()** annotation from JMS [serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations)

```php
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
 */

public function getAuthorsCustom()
{
    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's weird that you keep reference to authors in path to some route
`@Route("/api/authors/{authorId}")`.

### Suggestion:

I would consider using ORM relations mapping like this:

**Book.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Author", mappedBy="book")
 */
private $authors;
```

**Author.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors")
 * @JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $book;
```

and then in your service:

```
$book = $entityManager->getRepository(App\Entity\Book::class)->find($id);

return $book;
```

and then in your controller:

```
$book = $yourService->getBook($book_id);

return new JSONResponse($book);
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
let bookJSON = JSON.parse(responseData);
let authors = bookJSON.authors;
```

### Workaround solution:

**AuthorRepository.php**

```
/**
 * @var $ids int[] array of author identifiers
*/
public function getAuthorsByIds(array $ids)
{
    // it should return array of author entities
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('author')
        ->select('author')
        ->where("author.id IN (?)")
        ->setParameter($ids)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**your controller**

```
$book = $bookRepository->find($id);
$authorIdentificators = $book->getAuthors();

// convert routes to array of ids
array_walk($authorIdentificators, function(&$route) {
    $route = explode('/', $route)[3];
});

$authors = $authorRepository->getAuthorsByIds($authorIdentificators);

// notice that your $authors private property is now array of objects (not array of strings(routes))
$book->setAuthors($authors);

return new JSONResponse($book); // now book JSON should have array of authors
```

Instead of repository method you can use this slow loop

```
$authors = $book->getAuthors();

// convert routes to array of entity objects:
array_walk($authors, function(&$route) {
    $route = $authorRepository->find(explode('/', $route)[3]);
});
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you very much for your help. I ve decided to follow second solution but i get this error "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given". 
And a question: why in the function we give two parameters ($route and $key) but we use just $route? Thank you !

Comment: What is the result of your `$book->getAuthors();`? I expect it to be array or strings: ["/api/authors/1", "/api/authors/2"]. 
`$route` should be each element of `$authorIdentificators` array so you have an array of arrays but not array of strings. Maybe getAuthors() returns something like this:
['authors' => ["/api/authors/1", "/api/authors/2"]]. I don't know, you let me know :)

`array_walk`'s callback could have 3 parameters and each is optional so the second one ($key) is useless here (thanks, i'll edit it).

Comment: I check it and $book->getAuthors() send me a Object. What do you suggest me to do ? I convert the object in array ?

Comment: I proceeded in this way: i get the authors and with a loop, i get an array for $authorIdentidicators but, even after un debug where i had the confirmation that this variable is an array, i get the same message of error "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"

Comment: Okey but you have to show me what is your `$authorIdentificators` variable. It has to be an array of strings.

Comment: You should serialize this object and make it iterable. This is all I can say to help you.
Now let's start guessing:

Since `getAuthors` method returns object it's 99% unexpected behavior.
I assume (yes, your question should be downvoted because I have to assume something) that is this Doctrine's Collection object. Then you should use `toArray()` method for this object to make it array and then convert that array to array of strings (like this one in your question).